# The method or operation is not implemented. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a test method that works fine on .Net Framework but is generating an error on EntityFrameworkCore when it reaches the link query. The error is "The method or operation is not implemented. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()"

Here's my test method

```
    [Fact]
    public void UserNeverLoggedOn2_Test()
    {
        var userDataSet = new List<User>
        {
            new User
            {
                UserId = 1,
                IsActive = true,
                CreatedBy = "WBrown",
                CreatedDate = new DateTime(2019, 5, 1,0,0,0,DateTimeKind.Utc),
                LastAccessDate = DateTime.MinValue,
                FirstName = "Joe",
                LastName = "Doe"
            },
            new User
            {
                UserId = 2,
                IsActive = true,
                CreatedBy = "WBrown",
                CreatedDate = new DateTime(2017, 5, 1),
                LastAccessDate = DateTime.MinValue,
                LastActionTaken = DateTime.Now,
                FirstName = "Jane",
                LastName = "Smith"
            }

        }.AsQueryable();

      
        var mockUserSet = Mock.Create<DbSet<User>>() ;
        Mock.Arrange(() => ((IQueryable<User>)mockUserSet).Provider).Returns(() => userDataSet.Provider);
        Mock.Arrange(() => ((IQueryable<User>)mockUserSet).Expression).Returns(() => userDataSet.Expression);
        Mock.Arrange(() => ((IQueryable<User>)mockUserSet).ElementType).Returns(() => userDataSet.ElementType);
        Mock.Arrange(() => ((IEnumerable<User>)mockUserSet).GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => userDataSet.GetEnumerator());


        var dbContextMock = Mock.Create<EFDbContext>(); // 
        Mock.Arrange(() => dbContextMock.Users).Returns(() => mockUserSet);

        //Act
        IQueryable<User> query = from u in dbContextMock.Users
                                 .Where u.UserId = 1
                                 select u;

        Assert.NotNull(result);
        Assert.Equal(1, result.First().UserId);
    }
```

Not sure why it works on .Net Framework and fails on .NetCore.

Comment: There's no reason to try to mock an EF Core DbContext like this as the In-memory provider does exactly what you try to do here

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos, thanks for your reply. Can you share a good link with an example using  In-memory provider?

Answer (score 0):

I found what the issue was. Telerik.JustMock requires to enable the profiler when mocking advanced object such as Linq Queries. I enabled the profiler and the unit test ran successfully.